# How to Show Hybrid Map Labels Over a Custom Tile Server in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

I have an image overlay that displays high-resolution imagery over the selected Google map (See an example of this in the [Google API Examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay)).  When in satellite view, this works very well.  However, when the user switches to the hybrid view, I noticed that none of the labels or streets are shown over my map overlay.  Does anyone know a way to get the streets and labels to be displayed on top of my map overlay?

-- BEGIN EDIT --

I did find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487427/can-the-google-maps-api-base-map-be-used-as-an-overlay-above-a-custom-map-layer).  However, I can't figure out how to not get a duplicate data street/label layer on the portion of the map where my custom overlay has no imagery.  If this is the best solution, then is there a way to hide the labels when the selected map type id is HYBRID?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do two things:

1. Add your custom tiles as the base map layer
2. Add a `StyledMapType` with labels only to the overlayMapTypes of your map

---

## Adding custom tiles as the base map layer

Refer to [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image) to create an `ImageMapType`, which I'm guessing is what you want in order to use your own custom map type tiles.

---

## Adding a StyledMapType with labels only

You can create a `StyledMapType`:

```
var featureOpts = [{
  elementType: 'geometry'
  stylers: [
    { visibility: 'off' }
  ]
}];

var labelsOnlyMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, {
  name: 'Labels Only'
});
```

You can then put it into the `Map`'s `overlayMapTypes`.

```
// assuming you made a Map called 'map'
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, labelsOnlyMapType);
```

I'm just going by what I think should happen here, but what you should end up with is

- your tiles on the bottom as the base map
- the `StyledMapType` with labels only appearing on top of the map